# Complicated views

Tags: views

I am working on a database system with Drupal 7. 
I have node types employee, experience etc.  With relationship (reference entity), each employ may have zero or more records in experience. 
Experience node type has a date field (with start and end date) and what I want  is to

1. Calculate a **duration** or each experience record from stat and end date.
2. Calculate total experience (sum of **durations**)
3. Display total experience (that is sum of the durations) in view of employee with other fields of employee

Example;

Employee VIEW 
E_code, Ename, total experience 
1   xyz  2 years and 3 months 
2   nmn 6 months 
3   abc 1 year 7 months

Employees records
Ecode, Ename, Ephone, etc. 
1   xyz  5458254 etc 
2   nmn 59457495 etc 
3   abc 45749  etc
. . . . .and so on

Experience records
E_code, exp_date
1    01/01/2010 to 01/03/2011
2   01/01/2011 to 30/06/2011
1   01/06/2012 to 30/09/2013
. . . . and so on

How to bring total experience of each employee in the Employee table View?

Another question how we refer node field i.e.  exp date for global math expression  or computed field? In other view i have date field and need subtract that from current date (now?) I thought the global math expression can do that by joint_Date - Now. But not sure. Note I don't need to save this duration in field it should appears in view on go.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you, you can use [computed_field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) for calculating the field or you can use the [Views Calc](https://drupal.org/project/views_calc).

Comment: Madhujya can you explain bit more, I am using views Calc which calculate the sum of a column/field, may be I can use aggregation with calc to group sum of each employee. if it were one node type it could be easy, but the main node type is employee (for which I have to make view) and sum of experience from experience node type need to be displayed in the employee view. If my questions is not clear may I rewrite ?

Comment: could you please provide me a screen shot of you view, May be i can help you, Provide the screen shot by editing your question and please mension what you want clearly on the screenshot

Comment: There is no screen shot as no view created yet. there 2 tables (node types) 1.employe 2.experience, experience has many experience records with start and end date and employee has single record of each employee. Now what I want to display the total experience of all employee summing from their experience table. first I have to calculate the duration of experience of each record from start and end date then sum this experience of each employee and display with employee information. the experience is connect with employee by Reference field. –

Comment: any help, or may I re-write the questions if this is not understandable?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, in Views_calc you can able to add a new field in your view, By calculating the difference of the two date field in the views Calc page, Than you can use the hook_views_pre_render(&$view) for calculating the days months and year to render to your view, use the php floor function to implement.

Comment: may be I could not explain the questions well. Now I am having idea how I can make the required view. Thank for ref. to views calc it helps in subtracting two days, but when I use Now() - date in views calc it says now value not allowed here.

Comment: ok, any way if you use the now() than inside the hook_views_pre_render(&$view) you can find out the difference with out using the views calc. Hope you understand

Comment: Thanks I have achieved the goal in one way, though need work more. Durpal is so easy if we know "how". besides I'd like to have your opinion on views calc and computed field what you think which is better one. I am using views calc it is very simple but yet not able to use now() function in it may be i am doing something wrong. considering to try computed field as it give option to use php coding.

Comment: Perfect sense..See i don't know about your structure and logic so i can't say which one is best, make some r&d on time than definitely you can fix your situation. Good luck

Comment: Thanks I achieved what I wanted except that I still can't use now() and round() in views calc.